# Can't connect to Apache server from the same IP

Tags: apache

I have an Apache2 server setup at my house with a domain name assigned to it (we'll say `example.com`).  I have it set up to forward all `http` requests to use `https`.

Using any internet connection *besides* the one at my house, I can connect to `https://example.com` just fine.  However, when I am at my house, `https://example.com` says `refused to connect`.  I *can* however connect to the external ip directly (i.e. `12.34.56.789/index.php`), both at my house and elsewhere, but only through `http`, not `https`.

Any idea what could be causing this?  Let me know which config files would be helpful to have and I'll edit my question to include them.

**Config Files**

Here is the apache ssl config

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
            ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
            DocumentRoot /var/www/html

            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

            SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cert.pem
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/privkey.pem
            Include /path/to/options-ssl-apache.conf
            ServerName example.com
            SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/chain.pem
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

and here is the `/path/to/options-ssl-apache.conf` file

```
# Baseline setting to Include for SSL sites

SSLEngine on

# Intermediate configuration, tweak to your needs
SSLProtocol             all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite          <list of cipher suits>
SSLHonorCipherOrder     on
SSLCompression          off

SSLOptions +StrictRequire

# Add vhost name to log entries:
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%v %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" vhost_common

#CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log vhost_combined
#LogLevel warn
#ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Comment: This is an issue with the port forwarding on your router.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the PHP or Apache.

Comment: Why would port forward allow me to connect from the outside but not the inside?

Comment: It may actually be a router limitation. Routers have issues when you try to do port forwarding and you're already on the inside. Some routers don't do it at all. I suspect in your case, you're running into a conflict with the port used to manage the router itself.

Comment: The simplest solution may be to use an `/etc/hosts` file that translates your domain name to the private IP, so you don't go through the router when you're already on your local network.

Comment: Awesome.  I'll give that a shot.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Any idea if using ssl would make a difference?  Because I am able to access it from the inside and outside when using http.

Comment: Yes, that was my earlier point. I suspect it uses SSL for the management interface, so it's not forwarding that port.

Comment: You probably have remote management disabled, so it doesn't use SSL for the management interface on the WAN interface, only the LAN interface. That's why it works from outside on SSL.